# In machine learning how to find feature interdepencies?

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, feature-selection

Given a data set of N features, wherein some the features in this set were derived from other features from the same set, I am trying to discover inter dependencies between features (something like this Input feature(s) -> output feature(s)).

Note that,there can be multiple dependencies in the same feature set.
Can someone suggest some technique to approach this problem.

Comment: Something like correlation or partial correlation?

Comment: Might worth to try CCA with polynomial features.

Comment: Do you know anything about the form of the dependence?

Comment: @user20160 - thank you for replying. There are all sorts of relations like if Feature1 is 'IPV4' and Feature2 is 'Voice' then feature 3 will be 'Dual'. Or, if Feature4 x Feature5 + Feature7 = Feature8. Single feature can be also be part of 2 or more separate dependencies.

Comment: @gunes, thanks for replying. I will definitely explore this direction.

Comment: @gunes, would you know (or be able to point me in the right direction to understand) how is CCA different then multiple regression. It seemed almost the same but I am sure I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

You could train a standard auto-encoder. An auto-encoder is a neural network that tries to learn a reduced dimensional representation of some data set.
Once you have trained the network, and you want to know which features the ith feature is related to, you can examine the partial derivative of the ith output activation with respect to all the inputs. This should give you a sense for where the relationships are likely to be, but might be challenging to decipher the exact nature of the relationship.

Comment: This seems overkill and overly complex, why not something simpler such as canonical correlation?

Comment: With an auto-encoder, if you suspect non linear relationships, you don't need to specify any non-linear/polynomial transforms on your features. The network will (probably) just learn them. The drawback is, once learned, it is difficult to say what the nature of the non-linear relationship is. As for complexity, it is relatively simple to code up using something like tensorflow.